# Photo Taking Application with Jokes

Tags: iphone

I plan to get an iPhone, one of the tricks I can think of is to use it to play a joke on my friends.

This is how the joke goes. I would ask my friend to pose for me in the name of testing the quality of the camera. As I snap his/her photos, instead of showing his/her real face, I want the snapshot to be replaced with a picture of a pig (say), or anything that would elicit laughter.

Is there such an app available?

Comment: You could save yourself the trouble and just pretend to take a picture, then show your friend an image from the "Photos" app. Har har. (Can you tell I'm not much entertained by such apps?)

Comment: @torbengb, I afraid that my hands are not fast enough for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uff, there are a “lot” of photo + fun applications in the App Store. Here’s a few I’ve tried:

- [Face Substitution](http://itunes.apple.com/es/app/substituya-su-cara-2-0/id376172525?mt=8)
- [Swap Faces](http://itunes.apple.com/es/app/iswap-faces/id305557780?mt=8): Very funny (has a Lite version)
- [Face It](http://itunes.apple.com/es/app/face-it-free-version-now-alien/id323727582?mt=8): Allows you to add overlays of things (glasses, mustaches, etc)
- [Face Melter](http://itunes.apple.com/es/app/face-melter/id287215619?mt=8): allows you to deform a face (it makes you laugh a lot to be honest)

I have performed a “Face” search in the AppStore for iPhone apps and there are quite a lot, I suggest you take a look at those.